# File upload does not work Laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload, controller

I'm trying to upload an image from a form and store it in my laravelproject. The folder I want to store these pictures in is calles battlePics and I made this folder on the assets level. The actual problem is that $filename remains empty after this function. This is my controller:

```
 if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
      $file = input::get('file');


      $string = str_random(40);

      $filename = hash("md5", $string) . $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $file->move('battlePics', $filename);

      $battle->picture = $filename;



    }

    $battle->save();
```

I use the md5 hash to create different filenames to avoid errors when an image with the same name is uploaded. Here is the view of my form:

```
<form id="battleForm" class="battleForm" action="" method="post" role="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="{{Auth::id()}}">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title of the battle?</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder=""><br>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="points">Points to be earned</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="points" name="points" placeholder=""><br>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group date">
      <label for="startdate">Startdate</label><br>
      <input type="date" id="startdate" name="startdate" placeholder=""><br>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group date">
      <label for="enddate">Enddate</label><br>
      <input type="date" id="enddate" name="enddate" placeholder=""><br>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description">What is the battle about?</label><br>
      <textarea type="text" id="description" name="description" placeholder=""></textarea><br>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group radiobuttons">
      <label for="group1">Want to start de battle right away?</label><br>
      <ul>
        <li><input class="radiobattle" type="radio" name="active" value="yes"> <span>yes</span></li>
        <li><input class="radiobattle" type="radio" name="active" value="no"><span>no</span><br></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group battleimg uploadbatlle field">
      <img id="previewNewFile" src="" style="height:100px; width:150px;display: none; " required="true"/>
      <input style="" type="file" name="file" id="file" required="true">
    </div>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="battleSubmit" class="battleSubmit" value="Add new Battle"><br>
    <input type="hidden" class="tokenReferEmail" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
  </form>
```

I really hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Just a note, `str_random()` still has a (insanely small) chance of generating a filename that does exist. Perhaps look into timestamping the file instead/as well, and also checking if that filename already exists before finalizing upload.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To send files using `POST` request, you need change encode of form to `multipart/form-data`. More details: [HTML <form> enctype Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp).

Without `enctype` data form send only some details about file.

Comment: This was half of the solution. I also had to change the:  $file = input::get('file'); to Input::File('file');

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that the "name" attribute must exist in the <input> tag, it's not enough to just have the "id" attribute, I wasted a lot of time with that issue.